# unable to fit dataset

Tags: fitting

I have two experimental datasets namely [Alpha]s and [Alpha]b. I have also a model by which both [Alpha]s and [Alpha]b are correlated. These have both x axis and y axis data.
Following is my model:
[Alpha]s = [Alpha]b*(1 - 0.10752 - [Phi]) + [Alpha]h*[Phi]
Also note that [Alpha]h is a parameter like [Alpha]s and [Alpha]b meaning for each x value, there must be a value of [Alpha]h like [Alpha]s and [Alpha]b have. [Phi] is a constrained parameter  and 0<[Phi]<1 and the value [Phi] will be same for each x value.

Here are my datasets:

```
 \[Alpha]s = {{0.307419`, 126.59545`}, {0.324497`, 
       132.15556`}, {0.341576`, 135.98975`}, {0.358655`, 
       139.3329`}, {0.375734`, 142.19993`}, {0.392813`, 
       144.51441`}, {0.409891`, 146.53364`}, {0.42697`, 
       148.41727`}, {0.444049`, 150.3881`}, {0.461128`, 
       152.52134`}, {0.478207`, 154.81602`}, {0.495285`, 
       157.1668`}, {0.5123640000000002`, 159.48474`}, {0.529443`, 
       161.75352`}, {0.546522`, 163.97932`}, {0.563601`, 
       166.30828`}, {0.580679`, 168.76935`}, {0.597758`, 
       171.44123`}, {0.614837`, 174.24702`}, {0.631916`, 
       177.09429`}, {0.648995`, 179.8681`}, {0.666073`, 
       182.48013`}, {0.683152`, 184.90531`}, {0.700231`, 
       187.20391`}, {0.71731`, 189.43387`}, {0.734389`, 
       191.69559`}, {0.751467`, 194.03471`}, {0.768546`, 
       196.43603`}, {0.785625`, 198.90063`}, {0.802704`, 
       201.34854`}, {0.819783`, 203.77823`}, {0.836862`, 
       206.14986`}, {0.85394`, 208.47862`}, {0.871019`, 
       210.72494`}, {0.888098`, 212.91813`}, {0.905177`, 
       215.00418`}, {0.922256`, 217.03235`}, {0.939334`, 
       219.01782`}, {0.956413`, 220.98276`}, {0.973492`, 
       222.92312`}, {0.990571`, 224.82008`}, {1.00765`, 
       226.44257`}, {1.02473`, 227.92883`}, {1.04181`, 
       228.9761`}, {1.05889`, 230.03396`}, {1.07596`, 
       231.02569`}, {1.09304`, 232.4356`}, {1.11012`, 
       234.18097`}, {1.1272`, 236.48344`}, {1.14428`, 
       238.96456`}, {1.16136`, 241.78428`}, {1.17844`, 
       244.4555`}, {1.19552`, 247.32921`}, {1.2126`, 
       249.94199`}, {1.22967`, 252.73252`}, {1.24675`, 
       255.22882`}, {1.26383`, 257.78845`}, {1.28091`, 
       259.99171`}, {1.29799`, 262.1084`}, {1.31507`, 
       263.74427`}, {1.33215`, 265.26644`}, {1.34923`, 
       266.29021`}, {1.3663`, 267.41113`}, {1.38338`, 268.54908`}}



 \[Alpha]b = {{0.307419`, 133.53647`}, {0.324497`, 
       140.23063`}, {0.341576`, 143.72017`}, {0.358655`, 
       146.80901`}, {0.375734`, 149.41738`}, {0.392813`, 
       151.70411`}, {0.409891`, 153.71632`}, {0.42697`, 
       155.67793`}, {0.444049`, 157.70953`}, {0.461128`, 
       159.86664`}, {0.478207`, 162.13644`}, {0.495285`, 
       164.41137`}, {0.5123640000000002`, 166.62528`}, {0.529443`, 
       168.77836`}, {0.546522`, 170.85621`}, {0.563601`, 
       172.95008`}, {0.580679`, 174.94797`}, {0.597758`, 
       178.17771`}, {0.614837`, 181.29644`}, {0.631916`, 
       184.32788`}, {0.648995`, 187.18725`}, {0.666073`, 
       189.85355`}, {0.683152`, 192.28979`}, {0.700231`, 
       194.55624`}, {0.71731`, 196.7254`}, {0.734389`, 
       198.91804`}, {0.751467`, 201.21776`}, {0.768546`, 
       203.62608`}, {0.785625`, 206.1522`}, {0.802704`, 
       208.69625`}, {0.819783`, 211.22936`}, {0.836862`, 
       213.68702`}, {0.85394`, 216.07385`}, {0.871019`, 
       218.3479`}, {0.888098`, 220.54926`}, {0.905177`, 
       222.6276`}, {0.922256`, 224.63816`}, {0.939334`, 
       226.60406`}, {0.956413`, 228.54852`}, {0.973492`, 
       230.48316`}, {0.990571`, 232.37353`}, {1.00765`, 
       233.96973`}, {1.02473`, 235.37277`}, {1.04181`, 
       236.22035`}, {1.05889`, 236.99327`}, {1.07596`, 
       237.59286`}, {1.09304`, 238.63345`}, {1.11012`, 
       240.0498`}, {1.1272`, 242.15409`}, {1.14428`, 
       244.5749`}, {1.16136`, 247.4536`}, {1.17844`, 
       250.33293`}, {1.19552`, 253.47564`}, {1.2126`, 
       256.47166`}, {1.22967`, 259.63727`}, {1.24675`, 
       262.53152`}, {1.26383`, 265.40652`}, {1.28091`, 
       267.87372`}, {1.29799`, 270.13095`}, {1.31507`, 
       271.83902`}, {1.33215`, 273.30001`}, {1.34923`, 
       274.19621`}, {1.3663`, 275.09744`}, {1.38338`, 276.06374`}}
```

I have tried with using NonLinearModelFit like

```
NonlinearModelFit[\[Alpha]s[
  x], {\[Alpha]b[x]*(1 - 0.10752 - \[Phi]) + \[Alpha]h[x]*\[Phi], 
  0 < \[Phi] < 1}, {\[Alpha]h, \[Phi]}, x]
```

This code shows some errors, most probably I could not write properly.
So, please help me to get rid of this.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. The first argument should be a list of {x,y} values, the seond argument a formula giving y as a function of x with parameters (constants) to be fitted, the third a list of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try `NMinimize`,  in this way it's easier to handle both datasets!

Assuming equal discretized x-values in both datasets( `\[Alpha]b[[All, 1]] == \[Alpha]s[[All, 1]] (*True*)` your model `\[Alpha]b == (\[Alpha]b (1 - 0.10752 - \[Phi]) + \[Alpha]h*\[Phi] )` is optimized as follows:

```
J = # . # &[ MapThread[ #1[[2]] - (#2[[2]] (1 -  0.10752 - \[Phi]) + \[Alpha]h*\[Phi] ) &, {\[Alpha]b, \\[Alpha]s}]];
NMinimize[J, {\[Phi], \[Alpha]h}]
(*{22.3003, {\[Phi] -> -0.106913, \[Alpha]h -> -68.341}}*)
```

Show the fit

```
ListPlot[Evaluate[{\[Alpha]b, MapThread[{#1[[1]],  (#2[[2]] (1 - 0.10752 - \[Phi]) + \[Alpha]h*\[Phi] ) } &, {\[Alpha]b, \\[Alpha]s}] /. opt[[2]]}], PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red },Joined -> {True, False}]
```

[image]